# Android Heap Fragmentation Strategy?

Tags: android, heap-memory, fragmentation

I have an OpenGL Android app that uses a considerable amount of memory to set up a complex scene and this clearly causes significant heap fragmentation. Even though there are no memory leaks it is impossible to destroy and create the app without it running out of memory due to fragmentation. (Fragmentation is definitely the problem, not leaks)

This causes a major problem since Android has a habit of destroying and creating activities on the same VM/heap which obviously causes the activity to crash. As a strategy to counter this I have used the following technique:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(isFinishing()) {
        System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This ensures that when the activity is finishing it causes a complete VM shutdown and therefore next time the activity is started it gets a fresh unfragmented heap.

*Note: I realise that this is not the "Android way" but given that the garbage collector is non-compacting it is impossible to continuously re-use the heap.*

This techinque does actually work in general, however it doesn't work when the activity is destroyed in a non-finishing mode and then re-created.

Has anyone got any good suggestions about how to handle the degredation of the heap?

*Further note: Reducing memory consumption is not really an option either. The activity doesn't actually use that much memory, but the heap (and native heap) seem to get easily fragmented, probably due to some large'ish memory chunks*

Comment: i had the same problem, and employed a similar solution. really terrible.

Answer (score 4):

Fragmentation is almost always a consequence of an ill conditioned allocation pattern. Large objects are frequently created and destroyed. In conjunction with smaller objects may persisting (or a least having a different lifetime) - holes in the heap are created.

The only working fragmentation prevention in such scenarios is: prevent the specific allocation pattern. This can often be done by pooling the large objects. If successfull, the application will thankfully acknowledge this with a much better execution speed as well.

@edit: yet more specific to your question: if the heap after a restart of the application is yet not empty, so what is there to remain on the heap? You confirmed that its not a problem of a memory leak, but this is, what it seems. Since you are using OpenGL - could it possibly be, some native wrappers have survived, because the OpenGL ressources have not properly been disposed?